# Saving credentials / token in a cookie?

Tags: cookies, asp.net-web-api, token, access-token, jwt

I have managed to get working the authentication which i know return a token (JWT) to the client. This token has an expiration date/time so I was thinking about saving the token in a cookie so future logins were authenticated but this is probably not going to work.

I then though about saving the username and password in a cookie although i know this isn't recommended??

Currently i have a form that accepts a username and password, a successful login will provide a token which is used to access other endpoints.

The form needs to include a "Remember Me" so an automatic login can occur.

What is the best way of achieving this ?

Should i be storing the username and password in the cookie, if not how do i automatically authenticate the next time the user arrives to my site. The token that i provide is going to be expired so is there any point in even storing this ?

thanks in advance

Comment: where did you finally saved your JWT cookie or server-side session ? could you please reply back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not store the user name or password in the cookie. Even if the cookie is encrypted, it is better to store a credential with short expiration time like the token in a cookie than a credential like password which has more shelf life.

Even in the ASP.NET Web Forms or MVC world (Forms Authentication), typically "Remember me" works only until the time the cookie expires. "Remember me" does not mean remember me for ever and there must be a finite time period for remembering. That time can be derived from a cookie. You can put the JWT in the cookie and set the cookie's life time same as JWT, say an hour. When the user comes back to your app within that time, the cookie will not expire and the user is automatically logged in. Otherwise, they have to re-login. Do not think about storing the user name - password and systematically logging in. Let the user enter the credentials and that approach will be more secure. BTW, make sure cookie is encrypted and is an HTTP only cookie.

This mechanism will be similar to Forms Authentication. In place of the authentication ticket, you will use your JWT. Instead of FAM reading the cookie, you will need to have your own HttpModule or a message handler to do that and establish the identity for the requests.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So I think i will store the token only in the cookie. I can then have an endpoint that validates the token again in case it has expired. Whats the length normally to expire cookie with a token. Google gmail seeems to be logged in forever ? Would it not be good practice to automatically renew the token once it expired so that there was no interruption ?? i.e. No more logging in ?

Comment: I don't think there is any thumb rule regarding the expiry limit. It is up to your business needs. BTW, OAuth 2.0 authorization code based grant has refresh token which can be used to obtain a new access token seamlessly without asking user creds but that is applicable only to server side and forbidden for client side because of the risks involved. You have to basically think about providing an ultra-pleasant experience of seamless login versus secure experience. If I need to login in once in a few hours, I will take that, as against my credentials stored somewhere a browser has control over.

Comment: The Oauth 2 spec recommends an expiration not exceeding 10 minutes (rfc6749).  The OAuth 2 security best practices specification--as well as most identify providers--recommend against putting an access token in a cookie, even an HTTP-only cookie, or in any persistent storage mechanism in the browser.  It's also recommended not to use JWTs for session.  This article summarizes token storage for front-end apps: https://medium.com/@benjamin.botto/secure-access-token-storage-with-single-page-applications-part-1-9536b0021321

Answer (score 2):

Google's authentication coookie is good for 14 days.

http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/dog-fooding-our-api-authentication

Comment: Thanks for the link, this is exactly your framework I am using. I didn't realize that google was only valid for 14 days....

Comment: So there should not be any automatic re-login after the 14 days. it should be expired and the user should be forced to login again?

Comment: That is your decision ;) I think 14 days makes sense (for google).